# Printing custom characters to LCD

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, lcd

I'm trying to make some custom characters to a 20x2 LCD. I'm using a Atmega µController to control the LCD with 4 bit interface.
All my commands to the LCD seems to work fine (except the custom char)?

Well my code to create the character are as follows:

```
  /***********************/
 // Custom Characters
 /***********************/
void LCD_CreateCustomCharacters (void) 
{

 // make CGRAM data available from MPU and set custom characters in CGRAM 1-5
 // make CGRAM data available from MPU and set custom characters in CGRAM 1-5

LCD_cmd (0x40); //starts customization at first CGRAM place

// 0 bar character

LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);
LCD_prt (0x00);

// 1 bar character

LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x10);
LCD_prt (0x00);

// 2 bar character

LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x18);
LCD_prt (0x00);

// 3 bar character

LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x1C);
LCD_prt (0x00);

// 4 bar character

LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x1E);
LCD_prt (0x00);

//5 bar character

LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x1F);
LCD_prt (0x00);

LCD_cmd (0x80); //returns to DDRAM

}
```

^ That code seems to ALMOST do the job but still there's something wrong when outputting some of the characters. At my display when i try to do a print of 0x1 which should be a "|" becomes to " | | ".
The rest of the characters works fine.

And i try to print the constructed characters with this command:

```
char customs[6] = {0x5, 0x4, 0x3,0x2,0x1,'\0'};
LCD_string(customs);
```

The code should construct 5 characters which should be used as a progress bar.
But it only prints out a "||" sign and a "|" sign?

Do you have any idea what im doing wrong? If you need more code or information feel free to ask ! :)

Btw the full source code I've written can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/kea-int-et/source/browse/#svn/branches/jeb).
I've added a picture of the "wrong character I get" [IMGUR LCD DISP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q7H2.jpg)

Comment: @abelenky Yep sorry about that, I fixed it now, hope it's better.

Comment: I deleted my last comment.... Sorry...  You send the address to which you want to store your custom character, but are you sending all the command that tell the display you want to write to the custom character location?  What is the display model you are using?  The one I use, you send a WRITE command, followed by the ADDRESS, then the custom data.  I only see an ADDRESS and DATA for your function call.  Maybe your display is different.

Comment: @RadioActiveEd - I'm not 100% percent but the call LCD_cmd(0x40) tell the LCD that we are doing the CGRAM so setting LCD_cmd(0x40 + 8*adress) should set the LCD to cgram and go to the location of the adress?

Comment: Is this 8 pixels wide?  Or less...  If 8, let's make a BLOCK.  Set all values to 0xFF and see if you get a block. or if 5 pixels wide set to 0x1F, etc...

Comment: It is 5 pixels wide when i print the full block it's all fine shows all pixels black. The only problem seems to be the 0x10*7, actually it shows 0x10*8 as the only one. All other characters has an empty bottom line.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment about 0x10*7 and 0x10*8 as the only one?  From your code, all characters DO have an empty bottom line.

Comment: @RadioActiveEd Yes that's the problem, in my code all characters are left with an empty bottom line. But one of them, when displayed shows a "used bottom line". I've added a picture that maybe makes a bit more sense..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56218/discussion-between-radioactiveed-and-mrsykkox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at your initialization routine and verify all timing constraints are met there as well as in the normal code.

These displays can require the use of delays that are fairly long.  A microcontroller can execute a single instruction in no time at all, so your delays need to be carefully crafted.

Displays are fun but you must treat them well to perform properly!

Comment: Thank you for your time, you were a great help!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to create binary characters. This is very easy and you can draw this by hand as well before coding it;

`byte exampleCustomCharacter[8] = { 
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
 B10000,
};`
The code above would use only one pixel block on the LCD (hence it being 8 lines tall and 5 lines wide), and would print a 1 column wide section for the progress bar. The 1's are powered pixels and the 0's are pixels turned off. Every column on the LCD will be a column of 1's on this. 
Hope this helped a bit.